# Interesting properties of a mathematical number theory game

Tags: number-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

The game, which is purely recreational, goes as follows:

Starting out with 1, you can employ any of two different generation rules:

- You can multiply by 3
- You can divide by two, rounding up (e.g. 3 divided by 2 is 2)

Solving the game, i.e. showing that you can reach every number is another interesting problem, although trivial in comparison to the property I am trying to define: complexity. Say **the complexity of an integer N is the shortest sequence of rules needed to reach N**.

As an example, the complexity of 9 is 2. The derivation has the following notation:

1,3,9.

So we write C(9)=2. There are some numbers, namely all powers of three, which have a low complexity. But even small numbers such as 4 or 10 are already very complex.

I need your help in researching the complexity of a number and its inherent properties (lower, upper bounds). The randomness seems to be insane, mostly stemming from the "round-up" rule, which yields unpredictable results.

I leave you with some derivations so that you can get a feel for how you reach a number:

(7): 1,3,9,27,14,7.
(5): 1,3,9,5.
(11): 1,3,9,27,14,7,21,11.
...´

I will be monitoring the comments for additional information requests.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) page. Your game is closely related to the $3n+1$-problem

Comment: I am of course aware of the Collatz Conjecture, but I don't think they have the same goals or even the same type of complexity. You can control which rules to apply.

Comment: What exactly your question? Do you wish to find a way to get the value of $C(n)$  without having to try the sequences to get to $n$?

Comment: I wish to find out whatever I can about C(n). Which numbers are more complex, and why. Is it truly random because of the round-up rule? A general approximation (say, C(n) is O(n) for most numbers)...

Comment: David-- Do you have a finitely calculable way to check that some "derivation" is shortest possible? I guess if you already have one of say length 7 it would be useless to use multiply by 3 more than so many times, certainly no more than 7 because that would be longer.

Comment: Right now I'm doing what I call the "reverse" tree. For any given number, you must reach it by a certain rule. In the case of 5, you can only reach it through 9 and 10, so I look for those, and this keeps on going. I also have a database of all possible numbers you can reach in N steps (for N<13, it gets complicated...)